# Add GeoJSON features from an API call in OpenLayers 4, layer not displayed

Tags: openlayers, geojson, features, api, vector-layer

I'm trying to create a little demo to show the data from our API into a map but I cannot see my layer

Here my code, is just basic for the moment, we just need to display the data:

```
const projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'EPSG:27700',
  getPointResolution: (r) => {
    return r
  },
  units: 'm'
})

var view = new ol.View({
  projection: projection,
  center: [383000, 398000],
  extent: [0, 0, 700000, 1250000],
  resolution: 28,
  resolutions: [140, 70, 28, 14, 7, 2.8, 1.4, 0.7],
})

var maplayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  extent: [0, 0, 700000, 1250000],
  preload: Infinity,
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: 'https://www.buchananmapping.co.uk/mapcache/?',
    params: {
      'LAYERS': 'bccache2',
      'TILED': true
    },
    ratio: 1,
    projection: 'EPSG:27700',
    tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
      resolutions: [140, 70, 28, 14, 7, 2.8, 1.4, 0.7],
      extent: [0, 0, 700000, 1250000],
      tileSize: [128, 128]
    })
  })
})

var appSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  projection: 'EPSG:27700',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
})

var appLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: appSource,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'rgb(85, 172, 238)',
      width: 2
    })
  })
})

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    appLayer,
    maplayer
  ],
  view: view
})

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.traffwebdev.uk/tro/v1/restrictions?epsg=&x=383666+&y=398197&area=&radius=500&output=',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      // reads and converts GeoJSon to Feature Object
      var features = (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(data.geometry)
      appSource.addFeatures(features)
    }
  })
```

Both my map and GeoJSON use `EPSG:27700` but I cannot see any features in the map, I can see that the call to the API is made.

Sorry I don't have a demo but if you copy the whole code is working, there is no other code a part from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at actual GeoJSON data, you'll see that it's coded in `EPSG:4326`, so reading features statement should be:

```
var features = (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(data.geometry, {dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: 'EPSG:27700'});
```

You'll also have to change order of layers in map declaration, otherwise features will be covered by base map:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    maplayer,
    appLayer
  ],
  view: view
});
```

Comment: thanks, we didn't realise that we actually store the feature in the DB in `EPSG:4326`, now it works properly.